# How to change or hide __nuxt and __NUXT__ keyword in page source

Tags: nuxt.js

Is there any way to change or hide the name of the __nuxt and __NUXT keywords that are automatically generated in the page source when the page is rendered by Nuxt.js?

[image: Page Source]

Comment: What is the issue with it?

Comment: I want to hide the language in which the application is written against web bots. Is there a different way to do this?

Comment: Hide that this is Nuxt, Vue or JavaScript? What are you afraid of? Web bots for spamming some form or some API keys? Please give more infos on what you're trying to hide here. This video may help: https://youtu.be/hOtZhNb4TKg Frontend is pretty much "public" but this is usually okay because you do not do anything sensitive. Nuxt **in full static** build is really secure by default since it's creating static files tho, more than any Node or PHP server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can custom both by using the [globals](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-global-name#the-globals-property) property

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
globals: {
  id: '__pizza', // replacing __nuxt
  context: '__FAJITAS__', // replacing __NUXT__
},
```

Meanwhile, I'm not sure how you can expect your Vue app to work if you do not provide any CSS selector as for the `id` mount point. On the other side, `context` is used for hydration as far as I understand, so this is pretty important too.

It also looks like full static (`yarn generate`) is not using the `context`? Not sure about this but either way, you should probably not try to remove those since they are the foundation of the framework.

PS: my starting point was this github issue: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1792

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer provided by kissu:

Alternatively you can change the `globalName` option in `nuxt.config.js` file, and it will affect all `globals` such as `id`, `context`, `nuxt`, etc.

More information about this option you can find in the [documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-global-name/)