# Change __nuxt and __NUXT__ keyword in Nuxt3

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

This is the same question as [Hide nuxt Keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67463109/how-to-change-or-hide-nuxt-and-nuxt-keyword-in-page-source) with the difference that I am using nuxt3. And there the solution does not work.

My config looks like this and I have already tried many other entries:

```js
    export default defineNuxtConfig({
        app: {
            head: {
                link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/png', href: '_nuxt/assets/favicon.png' }]
            }
        },
        globalName: 'mmmm',
        runtimeConfig: {
            globalName: 'ddd',
            globals: {
                id: '__pas',
                context: '__PAS__'
            }
        }
    })
```

As you can see I even have to put it hardcoded in the favicon because ~/assets and ~assets don't work.
Is there any way in nuxt3 to change the nuxt global name?

For the assets problem I posted a separate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74485982/favicon-loading-from-assets-is-not-working-in-nuxt3)

To see what I mean:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

## change root element's id or tag

if you want to change the root element's id or tag you can use these two configurations:
`rootId` and `rootTag`

learn more: https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config#rootid

## change The folder name for the built-site assets

but if you want to change The folder name for the built-site assets. you can use this config: `buildAssetsDir`

This is set at build time and should not be customized at runtime.

**! don't use `assetsPath` because it is deprecated.**

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    app: {
        buildAssetsDir: 'something/',
        head: {
            link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/png', href: "/something/assets/images/logo.png" }]
        },
    },
})
```

by default buildAssetsDir's value is `_nuxt` but you can change it.

[image]

learn more: https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config#buildassetsdir

Comment: No. That does not work. rootId is the id of the div Element. But I mean all the nuxt references in loading scripts and the like. I updated my post with a picture of the source code where the tags are that I mean.

Comment: I added a screenshot to my answer pls check it.

Comment: but i don't know how you can change that `__NUXT__`