# Favicon loading from assets is not working in nuxt3

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I am trying to load favicon from assets in nuxt 3 but it does not work except if I hardcode _nuxt in front of it. My config looks like this and this works:

```js
    export default defineNuxtConfig({
        app: {
            head: {
                link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/png', href: '_nuxt/assets/favicon.png' }]
            }
        },
```

But according to documentation it should be something like this:

```js
    ~assets/favicon.png
```

or

```js
    ~/assets/favicon.png
```

but both don't work.
Any way to do it as documented or is this a bug?

AddOn Info: If using the links in a vue component it works and the favicon loads correctly if I show it on the page.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't do this because nuxt don't convert paths in the head object and sets exactly your path in the head and after build, there is no assets file.

you can use `_nuxt` or this :

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    app: {
        buildAssetsDir: '/something/',
        head: {
            htmlAttrs: { dir: 'rtl', lang: 'fa' },
            link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/png', href: "/something/assets/images/logo.png" }]
        },
    },
})
```

by default buildAssetsDir's value is `_nuxt` but you can change it.

read more: https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config#buildassetsdir

## Another solution

Why you don't use public/ directory for that because:

> The public/ directory is directly served at the server's root

and why do you need a module bundler to process your favicon? so you can use this:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    app: {
        head: {
            link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/png', href: '/favicon.png' }]
        }
    },
```

read more: https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/public

Comment: This works. Both solutions. The first does not remove all occurrences of nuxt word but at least I can load from assets folder if I want.

Comment: Actually the assets solution only runs with the dev server. If I npm run build and npm run preview it does not server the favicon anymore from assets. But the second solution works in nuxt3 also in production.

Comment: "Why do you need a module bundler to process your favicon?" Because my source svg file usually contains additional layers and meta information that I do not want to publish.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it with static folder settings.

```
export default {
  static: {
    prefix: false
  }
}
```

or

```
export default {
  build: {
    publicPath: 'https://cdn.nuxtjs.org'
  }
}
```

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/static/

Comment: using the static folder works but the folder settings you describe using "static" and "prefix" is not available in Nuxt3. But that means that assets-folder cannot be used in the nuxt.config.ts !?

Comment: Actually I was wrong. static folder does not work. public folder works.

Comment: Made an error testing this. It does not work! It is serving from public folder. Not static.